# XY to Line tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I wish to generate line with approximately 4061 xy coordinate from .csv file. However when i tried to execute using the xy to line tool the resulted map(photo 1) only showed half of the coordinate and the rest went missing(original photo 2).

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is in your CSV fie for one line that you have noticed missing?  What happens when you try to use the xy to line tool to create that?  What were the precise steps, and parameter values used in your workflow?

Comment: Make sure both xy coordinate pairs are in the same projection